# Two classes in my java app have the same Qualified name

Tags: java, spring, maven, jaxb, avro

I have maven module setup and one class is present in two modules with same name and package structure. `com.expd.common.etms_functions_shared_service_types.v2.ExportConsol`

These classes are generated during a maven build. One from a wsdl and the other from avro schema and both the wsdl and avro schema are not in our control. The app picks up only 1 at run time excluding the other which is expected.

Is there a way I can use both without having to rename them or change the package name?

Comment: As far as I know, nope.  You could maybe mess around with class loaders somehow, but I doubt the result would be very stable or easy to work with, if it works at all.

Comment: avro is open source, I would suggest that you fork the project and make the changes you need. https://github.com/apache/avro

Comment: You can try to construct a jar with relocated classes using the maven shade plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html

Comment: @JFMeier that plugin seemed promising but it did not work. My guess is this plugin would work if we are importing a jar or dependency. Since these xsd files are part of the module this plugin did not work.

Comment: @Frozendragon - that does not make sense. My avro schemas are built by another project within our company and apache avro has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. You need keep these classes in separate class loaders, so they naturally did NOT know about each other.

However renaming (e.g. using [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html)) would be much simpler and convenient solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't separate class loader the basic beahvior is that if the same class with FQN is just loaded the second occurrence during class discovery will be ignored. So i'm suggesting to keep one version of your class during class loading, deploying one jar containing that class in order to avoid confusion.